# Accept-language - Browser support for rare languages

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, language-support

I am developing a web application and I was planning to depend on the browser's Accept-Language header for user language preference setting. I just found out that I cannot freely define my accepted languages in Chrome/Chromium/Firefox. Take North Sami (se) for an example. The browsers have lists from where I have to choose from and Sami languages are unavailable, even though the languages have ISO language codes. It does not make sense to me to deliberately strip out and discard certain languages from the ISO 639-x list. Is there any workaround?

[Certain standardized language codes](https://datahub.io/core/language-codes)

Comment: As regards FF you may want to go to `about:config` and edit `intl.accept_languages` manually. (Untested.)

Comment: Thank you. That seems to work. There is a similar setting for Chrome but how could I edit that?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289597/webdriver-how-to-specify-preferred-languages-for-chrome/11375463

Comment: For Chromium there's [Advanced language switcher][1] but North Sami is not supported... How hard can it be to import a table with all entries...

  [1]: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-page-language-sw/mhgjlbolkmcookadjpolimbddngjgbol

Comment: I have never done anything similar with Chrome/Chromium. Hopefully someone else can help with it.